# Redirect to target url and add query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I'm trying to redirect just one page on a site to another one using htaccess. I'm new to this, but have been reading and reading everywhere to figure out how to do this, but without success.

I would like to redirect `www.example.se` to `www.example.se/index.php?template=<templatename>`

Is that possible and how would I approach that? So sorry if I'm asking a stupid question here, but really can't find a solution and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Redirect / /index.php?template=<templatename>
```

Add a `301` right after `Redirect` if you want it to be permanent.